# Undetermined permissions on expo notifications

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

Im building an app on EXPO and react native, and im trying to configure notifications.
Im trying on the expo app on an actual iphone, and i get "undetermined" permissions.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible in two situations.

- If we run the project in simulator or
- If we don't have proper notification's setup like configuring .p8 or .p12 files

Following thread may help you more :
https://forums.expo.io/t/ios-push-notification-permission-status-undetermined/19395/3